# Sorting A List Comprehension In One Statement

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I noticed something I didn't expect when writing a script this morning. I tried to use a list comprehension and sort it all in one statement and got a surprising result. The following code summarizes my general use case, but is simplified for this question:

```
Transaction = namedtuple('Transaction', ['code', 'type'])

my_list = [Transaction('code1', 'AAAAA'), Transaction('code2', 'BBBBB'), Transaction('code3', 'AAAAA')]

types = ['AAAAA', 'CCCCC']

result = [trans for trans in my_list if trans.type in types].sort(key = lambda x: x.code)

print result
```

Output:

```
None
```

If I create the list using the comprehension, then sort it after the fact, everything is fine. I'm curious why this happens?

Comment: the `sort` methods sorts the list *in-place* and then returns `None`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The method `list.sort()` is sorting the list in place, and as all mutating methods it returns `None`.  Use the built-in function [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) to return a new sorted list.

```
result = sorted((trans for trans in my_list if trans.type in types),
                key=lambda x: x.code)
```

Instead of `lambda x: x.code`, you could also use the slightly faster `operator.attrgetter("code")`.

Answer (score 7):

you want the `sorted` builtin function.  The `sort` method sorts a list in place and returns `None`.

```
result = sorted([trans for trans in my_list if trans.type in types],key = lambda x: x.code)
```

this could be done slightly better by:

```
import operator
result = sorted( (trans for trans in my_list if trans.type in types ), key=operator.attrgetter("code"))
```

Comment: Note that passing a list comprehension to `sorted()` results in a copy of the list being made.  This isn't necessarily slower, but might result in higher memory consumption.

Comment: You need to enclose the generator expression in parentheses.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- You don't need parenthesis do you?  `sorted( x for x in xrange(10) )` works just fine for me

Comment: You *do* need them if there is a second argument.  If the generator expression is the only argument, you can leave them out as a special exception.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You're right about the parenthesis -- I guess this is one special case which is special enough to break the rules...  Thanks (learn something new every day :).  Also, does the list comp really take up that much more memory?  All the objects in the list are already in existence -- It seems to me that you're really just creating the overhead of a list + len(lst)*sizeof(pointer), but I don't know the details of how this stuff actually works.

Comment: You are right about the overhead – it's not too bad, and it might even be slightly faster than the generator expression.  I'd simply prefer the generator expression here because it's conceptually what I want.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- I agree with the generator expression being what is wanted here.  I've just always wondered how much overhead is really avoided by using a generator vs. a list-comp.  Of course, if the expression is instantiating new objects, then you really start to see a difference in memory usage between a generator and list-comp.  Thanks for verifying what I thought I already knew.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `.sort` on a list returns `None`. It makes perfect sense that this result is then assigned to `result`.

In other words, you create a list anonymously with a list comprehension, then call `.sort`, and the list is lost while the result of the `.sort` call is stored in the `result` variable.

As others have said, you should use the `sorted()` builtin function in order to return a list. (`sorted()` returns a sorted copy of the list.)