# Reducing number of lines using lis comprehension

Tags: python-3.6

I have written below code to sort elements of list and its working fine(without using sort function).
I was just wondering if i can reduce the number of lines using list comprehension.
Please advice if this can be done.

```
list1=[5,1,4,2,3,8,0,9,12,7]
list2=list1
list3=[]
len1=(len(list1))

for i in range (len1):
    for j in range (len(list2)):
        curr=list1[j]

        if (j> 0):
            if (prev > curr):
                prev=prev
            else:
                prev=curr
        else:
            prev=curr

    idx=list2.index(prev)
    del list2[idx]
    list3.append(prev)
print(list3)
```

Comment: Almost certainly - but the real question is why do you want to do this? If a comprehension is hard to design, it is likely to also be hard to understand, which arguably makes the code worse.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting A List Comprehension In One Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433886/sorting-a-list-comprehension-in-one-statement)